# Calling function type alias instead of function

Tags: c++, gcc, language-lawyer, type-alias, compiler-bug

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using f = void(std::string);

void fcorrect(f func, std::string s) {
    func(s); // calling function
};

void fmistake(f func, std::string s) {
    f(s); // calling type alias instead of function
};

void myprint(std::string s) {
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
};

int main() {
    std::string s = "message";
    fcorrect(myprint, s);
    fmistake(myprint, s);
    return 0;
}
```

Function `fcorrect` receives `myprint` function and a string as arguments and prints this string as expected.
Function `fmistake` contains a deliberate mistake - it calls *type alias* `f` instead of function `func`. It prints nothing.

I wonder what's happening under the hood when the latter function call takes place? Namely, why no compile time or runtime error are thrown?

Comment: `f(s)` is a declaration, equivalent to `f s;` (redundant parentheses are allowed). Which in turn is equivalent to `void s(std::string);`, a forward declaration of a function named `s`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat It's not. A cast wouldn't have compiled. You can't cast a `std::string` to a function type. Besides, you can put any other name there, e.g. `f(xyz);`, and [it'd still compile](https://godbolt.org/z/xe66q5bej).

Comment: I would use `using f = std::function<void(std::string)>;` (and pass the string by const &). And somthing like `std::declval<f>().(s)`

Comment: I don't think redefinition of `s` as different kind of symbol is allowed. [Both Clang and MSVC reject your code](https://godbolt.org/z/f5Mxnvs5s).

Comment: *why no compile time or runtime error are thrown* Because you haven't enable all and extra compiler warnings and turned them into errors.

Comment: @273K Yes, invoking g++ with -Wall produces warning ```unnecessary parentheses```

Comment: @IgorTandetnik One thing I don't understand though - if it's taken as a forward declaration of a function, why doesn't it need a return type?

Comment: @PaulSanders What do you mean? The type of `s` is `f` - a function taking `std::string` and returning `void`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated by commenters, `f(s)` is a declaration. The crucial wording is here:

> There is an ambiguity in the grammar involving *expression-statements* and *declarations*: An *expression-statement* with a function-style explicit type conversion as its leftmost subexpression can be indistinguishable from a *declaration* where the first *declarator* starts with a `(`.
> In those cases the statement is considered a *declaration*, except as specified below.
>
> [ *Example 2:*
>
> ```cpp
> class T { /* [...] */ };
> // [...]
> T(a);   //  declaration
> // [...]
> ```
>
> -- *end example* ]

- [[stmt.ambig] p1](https://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.ambig#1)

It doesn't matter what the type is (class, function, etc.), `T(a)` is a declaration if `T` names a type.

The declaration `f(s)` does nothing here because it is not used, and is equivalent to `f s` or `void s(std::string)`. `s` is already a function parameter `std::string s` in this context, so GCC is wrong about allowing it. GCC also allows:

```cpp
void fmistake(f func, std::string s) {
    void s(std::string);
}

// GCC also allows the following (in C++ mode)
void foo(int x) {
    // GCC rejects this as re-declaring a symbol in C, but not in C++ mode.
    void x(int);
}
```

This is a known [GCC bug 52953](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52953), and has first been reported in 2012.

Comment: It seems that grinding wheels are finally [in motion](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/attachment.cgi?id=55820&action=edit)